# ToolbarLayout for a PolylineConnection's children?

Tags: layout, eclipse-rcp, parent-child, eclipse-gef

Is there a way to specify a layout for children of a `PolylineConnection`?

I want to add several `Label`s to a `PolylineConnection` at `ConnectionLocator.MIDDLE` without the use of a container figure for the labels.

Both `PolylineConnection` and `Label` have `EditParts`, and the label's model objects are children of the polyline connection's model objects.

Ideally I want to add all label children of a polyline to `ConnectionLocator.MIDDLE` in a `ToolbarLayout`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to achieve what I wanted:

Very generally, the first child must be added at `ConnectionLocator.MIDDLE`, and the rest of the children *relative* to the child before them with the help of `RelativeLocator` like this (line would be in a loop over all figure children in connection's edit part):

```
figure.add(childFigure, 
           new RelativeLocator((IFigure) figureChildren.get(currentIndex - 1), 
                                   0.5, 
                                   1.7);
```

I've written a [blog post](http://blog.sdruskat.net/eclipse-gef-connection-layout/) with more details.

Comment: Interesting and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is mix two layouts: on the first hand you want to use a `ConnectionLocator.MIDDLE` to locate the figures, but on the other hand you want to have the figures at this location to have their own layout.

The only solution you have is to create a figure that uses a `ToolbarLayout` and locate it in the `Polyline` using the `ConnectionLocator`

Comment: You're right, mixing two layouts is impossible. However, I don't want to use a container figure, as child figures are added/removed dynamically via `getModelChildren()` in the connection edit part. I've found a hack that works, using `RelativeLocator` (see my solution).